# Cannot resolve symbol drawable

Tags: android

Cannot find symbol
Drawable flag = Drawable.createFromStream(stream, nextImage)

When I try to `import com.mypackage.url.R.drawable` at the top, it gets greyed out.

How do I load Drawable?

Answer (score 1):

You have to `import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;`
R is used to access resources under 'res' folder and not for classes